# vb.net Word Document Replace Strings Images

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word, ms-office

I am trying to create mail merge process with word document (images, text, html). I am finding help online for a desktop application, but trying to do it from a web aspx page.

here is code I tried

```
    Dim wordDoc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, True)
    Using (wordDoc)
        Dim docText As String = Nothing
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream)

        Using (sr)
            docText = sr.ReadToEnd
        End Using

        Dim regexText As Regex = New Regex("Hello world!")
        docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "Hi Everyone!")
        Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create))

        Using (sw)
            sw.Write(docText)
        End Using
    End Using
```

but can not even run. I get an error in visual studio 2015.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30002 Type 'WordprocessingDocument' is not defined.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: What you're asking is completely unclear, and too broad. I suggest you begin by removing the second thing you tried so that we can concentrate on just the one thing. The tell us the error message. Also, are you using the Open XML SDK? It sorta looks like it, but the approach is a bit odd... It might also help us help you if you provide the link(s) you're looking at online. You can click on the "EDit" link below your question to remove the "too much" and add the additional information.

Comment: Ok, thanks for comments, I modified, I am not sure if open xml of sdk. I have not specified either in my code.

Comment: Then you more or less just copied code from the link you still haven't provided and hoped it would run? The error message indicates you have, indeed, NOT referenced the Open XML SDK, but are trying to use namespaces associated with it. I recommend you start on this page, work your way through the material to understand what the SDK is and how it works, and download/install it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. I did download open xml, but how do I add as a reference in 2015? Instructions out there are for visual studio 2010.

Comment: It shouldn't really be much different? Something like Project/Add Reference / Browse, navigate to the folder where the SDK is installed (probably Program Files/Open XML SDK) and select the DLL? WindowsBase.dll is in the list of .NET assemblies.